# jQuery UI with RequireJS v.1.11.1 - script error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, requirejs, amd

I am following this guide: https://github.com/jquery/learn.jquery.com/blob/master/page/jquery-ui/environments/amd.md

And I am trying to require `jquery-ui/sortable` and `jquery-ui/draggable`, but it fails, saying:

`Uncaught Error: Script error for: lib/jquery-ui/draggable`

This is the folder structure:

[image]

This is how I load it:

`define(['jquery', 'lib/jquery-ui/draggable', 'lib/jquery-ui/sortable'], function($) {`

What am I doing wrong?

Also it surprises me there is no such file, "sortable", in jquery-ui - but the documentation tells me this is the way. Using v1.11.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the package available from download from the [official place](http://jqueryui.com/): is a contacted version.

It wasn't pretty easy to find the library that I was looking for, but finally found it @ [github](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui):

Comment: What *exactly* do we have to download from that link to get the proper package?